# Pycharm background for project tree and other service windows

Tags: pycharm

I changed default colour scheme of Pycharm (4.x) but it affects only editor area. I'd like to do the same with project tree, stack trace, watchers and all other windows. How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Theme